# could not broadcast input array from shape (0,495,64,1) into shape (496,64,1)

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array with shape (0,495,64,1) and I want to reshape it into (495,64,1), I have tried to use reshape and squeeze and delete on NumPy but I didn't get any result.

```
ValueError                               
 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-26-00b8e2195d61> in <module>

      2 print("loading training data...")

      3 training_file = train.fn.values

----> 4 training_data, training_label = loading_data(training_file, sound_extractor)

<ipython-input-24-ea9db93ded7f> in loading_data(files, sound_extractor)
     27             print(cur_spectro[:,:,:].shape)
     28             print(data[i * seg_num + j, :, :, :] .shape)
---> 29             data[i * seg_num + j, :, :, :] = cur_spectro
     30             label[i * seg_num + j] = lines[i][-2]
     31 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0,495,64,1) into shape (496,64,1)
```

Comment: Could you give more code? Especially `cur_spectro`, `data`, `label`.

Comment: cur_spectro is an array of (0,496,96,1) and data is an array with shape (11906,496,96,1)

Comment: 2 questions: 1. why the err report indicates that one dim=495 and the other is 496? 2. why the size of first dim of cur_spectro is 0?